# Storing a PKDrawing object to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, pencilkit

I am trying to add Apple Pencil support to my mind mapping app.  I already use Core Data within my app for data persistence which all works fine without any bugs.

I have my Apple Pencil features working fine but I'm having trouble storing the Apple Pencil data.

Ive tried to add a PKDrawing object to my MindMap data model but I keep getting a compile time error 'cannot find type 'PKDrawing' in scope'

As far as I am away I can store the PKDrawing object into  core data and then fetch it back out when the app loads.  But I'm obviously not doing something right.

[image][image]

Any help is greatly appreciated folks.

Thank you

Update:

So I've used:

```
func convertToData(pkdrawing: PKDrawing) -> Data {
    let data = pkdrawing.dataRepresentation()
    return data
}
```

Then updated my model data and savedContext which all seems to work ok.  The problem is when I try and initialise the data on opening the app.  I have:

```
func createDrawing(data: Data) -> PKDrawing {
    
    var loadedDrawing: PKDrawing
    
    do {
        try loadedDrawing = PKDrawing.init(from: data as! Decoder)
        return loadedDrawing
    } catch {
        print("Error loading drawing object")
        return PKDrawing()
    }
}
```

which gives me error:

Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.Data' (0x1f3851a98) to 'Swift.Decoder' (0x1ee5381a8).
2021-09-24 06:22:58.912173+0100 MindMappingApp[1137:612856] Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.Data' (0x1f3851a98) to 'Swift.Decoder' (0x1ee5381a8).

I tried:

try loadedDrawing = PKDrawing.init(from: data as! Decoder)

as:

try loadedDrawing = PKDrawing.init(from: data)

but I kept getting:

Argument type 'Data' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'

any ideas?  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to store the `PKDrawing` directly, store the `Data` associated with it instead.

Your Core Data model will have a field with the type `Data` (or Binary Data if you're using the GUI).

When you need to actually use that data and covert to/from the `PKDrawing`, you can use:

- `init(data:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkdrawing/3281882-init
- `dataRepresentation()` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkdrawing/3281878-datarepresentation