How to Save and Load PKDrawing
I want to use SwiftData to store my PKDrawing data. I'm not interested in using CoreData or UserDefaults. I need the app to save the current drawing state when it is closed and to display the saved drawing when it is reopened.

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct Test_DrawingApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }.modelContainer(for: DrawingData.self)
    }
}

import SwiftData

@Model
class DrawingData {
    var drawingData: Data?
    init() {
        drawingData = nil
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CanvasView()
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import PencilKit

struct CanvasView {
    @State var canvasView: PKCanvasView = PKCanvasView()
    @State var toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
}

extension CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        let contentWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let contentHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        canvasView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
        canvasView.drawingPolicy = .anyInput

        canvasView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        canvasView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()

        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
        toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)

        return canvasView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {}
}

This issue has been challenging me for a while. Could anyone suggest how to achieve this? Thank you very much.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69307314/5133585
